# How to prevent enter key triggering submit

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using `Formik` for a little form in a `React` app.

The method `handleSubmit` is triggered when user hits the enter key.

Is there a way to prevent that triggering? 
I didn't find anything in the formik docs...

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't do this. This is done for various reasons most notably for accessibility.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could add an `onKeyDown` handler like this:

```
/**
 * Stop enter submitting the form.
 * @param keyEvent Event triggered when the user presses a key.
 */
function onKeyDown(keyEvent) {
  if ((keyEvent.charCode || keyEvent.keyCode) === 13) {
    keyEvent.preventDefault();
  }
}

/**
 * Sample form component.
 */
function Example() {
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ name: "" }} onSubmit={() => console.log("Submit")}>
      <Form onKeyDown={onKeyDown}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <Field id="name" name="name" type="text" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

See CodeSandbox [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0pmx8q37yl).

Comment: It will block textarea enter

Comment: You can also use the `event.key` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: @JomonJohnson is there a way not to block textarea except adding event listener to every input/textarea field?

Comment: I would recommend using this: if (e.code === 'Enter' || e.code === 'NumpadEnter') {}. keyCode will be deprecated soon (if not already).